# TPK location on windows file system

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I'm doing a proof of concept on a Windows 10 tablet with the Anywhere 7.6.2.1 Work Execution app and am trying to setup offline maps using a TPK file.
The instructions on the product knowledge center state:

> For Windows devices, this folder location is
>   windowsLocalMapUrl="\folder_path\map_file_name.tpk"

But where is this path relative to in the windows file system? I've tried in multiple areas in the package installation directory with no luck.

Thanks, 
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application is found under the packages folder (it's installed per-user). %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\a02b50fe-bb55-4be5-8bd9-6c2f93cef175_8pwz203q7fbs8.

The final filename may be different, it's based on the guid that is set during the build process.

I dug around a bit in the mapFatoryHelper.js file and found that if you have an online map provider URL then it'll override the offline maps. Do you happen to have providerUrl defined and that's the case?

Comment: Thanks - just needed to change the GUID as stated and add \LocalState to the end.